# Pagespeed still works on a new server even though it shouldnt

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, pagespeed

I had mod_pagespeed installed on my previous server. I didn't use it and disallowed via .htaccess because after some testing it turned out that it actually slowed down my site. So it remained "disallowed" via .htaccess for a long time.

Today I moved to a new server and migrated user accounts using cPanel VHM migration feature. Supposedly it migrates only accounts and not configuration, but I have many problems now and I suspect this is primarily due to pagespeed. It's not installed on the new server because I dont need it, but somehow various logs and console messages show that pagespeed versions of files are still requested from time to time like the following "d14dafe2dc85d5ff8142236c3f55e0d4.pagespeed.jm.ReWsy_33cT.js" which causes random 404 errors and even 500 internal server errors.

How can it request pagespeed versions if pagespeed isnt installed? how is it possible? can anyone explain, please.

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed it. It was DNS problem.. data was being loaded from both servers. That is, had to wait for DNS propagation to finish.